# Auto click button script for tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript

am trying to create a user script which would click the following button as soon as possible  on loadiing the page.

```
<button class="btn" tabindex="10" disabled="disabled" onclick="ValidateAndSubmit('1')" title="" pay-tab="1">Do now</*button>
```

please help as i am trying from long time but failing to do so.

i tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
setTimeout(function()
 { document.getElementById("btn").click(); },1000); 
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please add your attempts and explain exactly where they went wrong?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("btn").click();
  },1000);
  </script>

I tried this but in vain.. and also tried some solutions from stackoverflow.

Comment: You can simply click the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19209364/edit) below your original post to add more information. It's really hard to read code pasted in the comment area...

Comment: how to put the code block for code?

Comment: You can read about using Markdown [in this help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(function() {
    window.addEventListener('load', ValidateAndSubmit('1'), false);
})();
```

`(function() {})()` defines a scope that is self executed without waiting for any events.

`window.addEventListener('load', ValidateAndSubmit('1'), false);` subscribes the function `ValidateAndSubmit` to `window load` event so that the function is executed on load. This is the same function you are trying to execute by clicking the button.

Comment: A little bit of explanation would go a long way with this answer.